# Sencha touch and disableCaching parameter

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Every time I refresh my application in the browser, with the disableCaching flag set to true in my app, the new view that I have added isn't being loaded by my app.
No matter how many times I hit refresh, the new view isn't loaded.  I have this in my app:

```
   views: ['Main', 'KittensList', 'TestMain'],
```

This is at the start of the application definition:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setConfig({disableCaching: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext', 'lib/touch2/src');
```

Yet regardless of how many times I hit refresh the new script isn't loaded in.
Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Did you try clearing browser cache and then refresh? Are you talking about production build or development version of the app?

Comment: I'm talking about the development version. I refreshed so many times my F5 button wore down! Surely I don't need to clear out the cache each time? I wanted to avoid this as all my passwords are then cleared for all the sites I use.

Comment: You do not need to clear your cookies, passwords or any other data. Just check the "Clear cache" box. You need to do this sometime because this browser's inherent property to cache a Javascript file.